# How to use push in React Router DOM v6

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I use react-router-dom v6, I saw that there were some changes.

I need to replace this:

```
return <Redirect push to={`/url/${this.state.myState}`}/>
```

with:

```
return <Navigate replace to={`/url/${this.state.myState}`} />
```

but I don't know to use the "push" on the v6.

Comment: All navigation in RRDv6 is PUSH by default unless passing the `replace` prop for redirection.

Comment: @DrewReese, Oh thank you for your answer, for my use case I just had to remove the replace, I had not understood that by default it was push, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explicit syntax in React Router v6 would be this:

`` <Navigate to={`/url/${this.state.myState}`} replace={true} /> ``

The ability to redirect has been removed from React Router. So this means there is no , redirectTo, or isRedirect, and no replacement APIs either.

Be aware that the v5  uses replace logic by default (you may change it via push prop), on the other hand, the v6  uses push logic by default and you may change it via replace prop.

So you do not need to specify `push` explicitly as it is a default from now on.

As specified in the migration guide:

```
// Change this:
<Redirect to="about" />
<Redirect to="home" push />

// to this:
<Navigate to="about" replace />
<Navigate to="home" />
```

Reference:
https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5